# best way to implementation this UI?

Tags: wpf, listview, wrappanel

[one button with wrapped list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSzQR.png)

my searched result are:

1.worst approach: put add button on the wrapped list view.

2.bad approach: set two data template for list view.

3.?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had something similar a while back. In the end I decided to add a fake data item where I needed the button.

Say I had a list of `MyDataItem`, I created a derived class `MyFakeDataItem` and added that at the end of the list, after I finished populating it. In the WPF I created two data templates, one for each class, and a selected to decide.

I think it turned out quite elegant, since it allowed me to easily override any real functionality I had on `MyDataItem`, and add a command on the fake one to suit my needs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Sara - True. I just don't think it's a bad solution. If done right, I think it's quite elegant. There's nothing wrong with multiple templates and template selectors.

Comment: I think it's wrong to embed only one button in listview, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "only one button". You don't add the button to the xaml. The button is created when you add the `MyFakeDataItem` to the list. You can add as much of these as you'd like.

Comment: my means that listview (or other similar controls) be used to display list of objects, not only one.

Comment: But you don't display only one. You use the same list to display all your items PLUS the button. You only use a different template for the button.